# can not access to service in postman

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i create a image of my project in nodejs .

i write `Development` yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-depl
  labels:
    app: user-depl
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-pod
      departemant: user
  template:
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: user-pod
          departemant: user
      spec:
        containers: 
          - name : user-pod
            image: kia9372/store-user
            ports:
             - containerPort: 4000
```

and create a `Services` :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
  labels:
    app: user-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-pod
  ports:
    - name: user 
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

and when i run this command `kubectl get services` it show me this :

> user-service        ClusterIP   10.109.72.253            4000/TCP            36m

and when i send request to this service in postman it not show me any thing .

```
https://10.109.72.253:4000/user
```

it show me this error :

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.109.72.253:4000

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: Is the kubernetes running locally? If not you cannot access, those are internal IP. Try to get access with kubectl port-forward svc/user-service 4000:4000. Then you can call 127.0.0.1:4000. Are you doing ssl termination inside your pod? Check http and https

Comment: it solved . how can access to service without port forwarding

Comment: CodeWizard already gave the solution. As an alternative you leave it as clusterip and use an ingress controller and an ingress configuration.

Comment: Just an additional tip: note that the ClusterIP is a private IP address (10.x.x.x always is - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). Private IP's can only be reached from the same network..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your service is not of type load balancer so you will not be able to access it.
- Since you did not specify any other type `ClusterIP` is the default for the Service.

#### `ClusterIP`

> Exposes the Service on a `cluster-internal IP`.
> Choosing this value makes the Service **only reachable from within the cluster**

Here is a sample code on how to access it using `NoodePort/ClusterIP`
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/05-Services

---

[image]
Img source: https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/service-types-in-kubernetes-24a1587677d6